# Caching with async calls

Tags: c#, caching, architecture

Could you please help me?
I developed web-based sysytem wich send async requests to server. Server takes big data from db and cache it. It takes ~5 sec. Next call Server search in cache so it takes ~ 0.05 sec.
For first time 5 sec is ok, but if I send more than 5 async requests in one time each thread create cache so it takes first time more than 20 sec.
How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this before, the solution is to marshal all the requests into a queue of some sort or set a busy flag up in the database/cache so that subsequent requests know something is working on the issue.

So first request flags as busy and performs request. Following requests see that it's busy and will wait until the flag is no longer marked as busy. Those requests should then be able to pull the cached copy.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting scenario. However you haven't specified how you cache the information and how your code runs.
If you are using ASP.Net caching (and WCF / Web service), I don't think it supports more complex scenarios like this one.
If you want some ideas for work-arounds (as I said, just ideas, nothing I have tried before) you can try to cache a flag with status "NotCached", "Caching" and "Cached".
Just note that you may have problems with concurrency if two requests are done at exactly the same time.
If it's not cached, you start the process and set the flag to "Caching". While you are caching you can decide what to do with the other coming requests. Use thread sleep (I wouldn't recommend) or go to the database, but don't cache again.
When the first request finishes caching, you set the flag to Cached and job done.
If you are using other technologies, you may be able to queue the requests and while caching process only one.
If you provide more details it will help analysing your scenario.